# ObjectPool code

Tags: c#

Here is a simple ObjectPool collection that I use for some of my classes. Could someone review it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Mango.Collections
{
    sealed class ObjectPool<T>
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentBag<T> _objects;
        private readonly Func<T> _objectGenerator;

        public ObjectPool(Func<T> objectGenerator)
        {
            if (objectGenerator == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("objectGenerator"); }
            _objects = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
            _objectGenerator = objectGenerator;
        }

        public T GetObject()
        {
            T Item;
            if (_objects.TryTake(out Item)) { return Item; }
            return _objectGenerator();
        }

        public void PutObject(T Item)
        {
            _objects.Add(Item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> public T GetObject()
> {
>     T Item;
>     if (_objects.TryTake(out Item)) { return Item; }
>     return _objectGenerator();
> }
> ```

This does not only gets an object but it also create a new one, a default one so the method name should be `GetObjectOrDefault`.

If you can use C# 7 you can simplify it as:

```
return _objects.TryTake(out T obj) ? obj : _objectGenerator();
```

---

> ```
> public void PutObject(T Item)
> {
>     _objects.Add(Item);
> }
> ```

I think you should not *invent* new vocabulary. Call it `AddObject`.

---

Parameter and variable names should be *camelCase* not *PascalCase* so it's `T item` or `T obj` and not `T Item`.

---

More C# 7. You can initialize the `_objects` inline with

```
private readonly ConcurrentBag<T> _objects = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
```

and make the constructor a one liner:

```
public ObjectPool(Func<T> objectGenerator) => _objectGenerator = objectGenerator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(objectGenerator));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks clean to me, but why is it Sealed? I can see this being useful as a base class for other things. It could be described in an abstract class or with an interface to the `GetObject<T>` and `PutObject<T>` methods.